# Recommended way of migrating Live PrasePlatform iOS/Android Project to Other Platform

Tags: parse-platform

Once we go live with ParsePlatform iOS/Android project, can we able to migrate to another Platform?

Please help us.

Comment: if you have to ask you are probably not able to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution at Firebase website with parse SDK and Firebase SDK

https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/parse-ios